# Is there a way i can cover margin-left in spite of margin:0 auto with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm fighting currently with a centered wrapper (centered with margin 0 auto). now i want to have a container beginning at the left until the centered wrapper begins. Is that possible at all with this given margin spec?

I would really appreciate some hints!

see also the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/TQhEa/1/

What i have now:
[image]

What I want to have:

[image]

My code:

```
<body>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <p><---- how can i cover the left side only with red without javascript but keeping the "0 auto margin?"

    </div>
</body>
```

my CSS:

```
body, html{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        top:0;
        margin:0;
        background-image: url('http://www.art-wallpaper.net/Full-Size-HD-Wallpaper29/images/HD%20Widescreen%20Wallpaper%2059.jpg');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
       -webkit-background-size: cover;
       -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
       background-size: cover;

}
#page-wrapper{
    background-color:red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
    top:0;
    margin-top:0;
    height:100%;
}
p {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font-size:30px;
}
}
```

Comment: You could put a second box 50% wide to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to set the `background-color` and position of `background-image`. Check out [this piece of code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/orHdE): 
**html**

```
<div id="page-wrapper">content</div>
```

**css**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #c11 url(http://placekitten.com/1000/1000) 100% 0 no-repeat;
}
#page-wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: thats an really interesting approach...do you know if that is for ie 7-10 ?

Comment: It should. There's nothing here IE wouldn't understand. ;)

Comment: @Jurudocs Try to play with `background-size` property. Although keep in mind that this one IE won't understand. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add 1 more DIV with the following CSS :

```
#left_div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #F00;
    display: table; /* note IE5-7 does not support this */
    z-index: 1;
}
```

and modify the current centered DIV `$('#page-wrapper')` to have higher `z-index` value

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra div with the property's `position: absolute;` `width: 50%;` `height: 100%;` and `z-index: -1;`

See: http://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/TQhEa/3/